# Headers don't have correct spacing

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Has anyone ever encountered this issue before with DataTables.js, when the table generates the headers don't have correct spacing

[image: Text]

However once I click on it, it corrects itself.
[image: Text]

My code is pretty straight forward

```
var table = $(reportID).DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'
            ],
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "pageLength": 100,
            scrollY: '40vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,

            columnDefs: [{
                targets: [0],
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="SNIP=' + data + '" target="_blank">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            }]
        });
```

Would anyone have any idea what is going on with this :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities to debug this issue.

1. Add width="100%" to the table tag and check.
2. If the table is initialized while it is hidden, use columns.adjust() when it is made visible. In case, this doesn't work, you may need to call it in little time using "`setTimeout`"

Comment: Hi Mayank, thanks for response, it seems that the scrollY seems to be the culprit that is causing the issue with Bootstrap. When disabled it works fine, but due to the amount of records, I need this enabled. The tables are indeed hidden on load and I have to use a timeout to render these correctly. I will look into the columns.adjust, hopefully I can get a fix there :)

Comment: Yeah just try to implement "columns.adjust()"  and it should resolve the issue.